# Reading sentences from a text file and appending into a list with Python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, append, text-files

I'm having trouble figuring out how I would take a text file of a lengthy document, and append each sentence within that text file to a list. Not all sentences will end in a period, so all end characters would have to be taken into consideration, but there could also be a '.' within a sentence, so I couldn't just cutoff searching through a sentence at a period. I'm assuming this could be fixed by also adding a condition where after the period it should be followed by a space, but I have no idea how to set this up so I get each sentence from the text file put into a list as an element.

The program I'm writing is essentially going to allow for user input of a keyword search (key), and input for a number of sentences to be returned (value) before and after the sentence where the keyword is found. So it's more or less a research assistant so the user won't have to read a massive text file to find the information they want.

From what I've learned so far, putting the sentences into a list would be the easiest way to go about this, but I can't figure out the first part to it. If I could figure out this part, the rest should be easy to put together.

So I guess in short,

If I have a document of `Sentence. Sentence. Sentence. Sentence. Sentence. Sentence. Sentence. Sentence. Sentence. Sentence. Sentence. Sentence.`

I need a list of the document contents in the form of:

```
sentence_list = [Sentence, Sentence, Sentence, Sentence, Sentence, Sentence, Sentence, Sentence, Sentence, Sentence, Sentence, Sentence]
```

Comment: So basically you are asking how to split out sentences in an arbitrary text document? That's a broad subject, can you narrow this down a little? What kind of inputs? Any specific language?

Comment: I don't know how I can be more specific - If I take a journal or scholarly article from online, put it into a text file (copy and paste into emacs), I need to take those sentences and put them in a list so they are more easily accessible and I can work with them.

Comment: could you provide an example which replicate this `but there could also be a '.' within a sentence` ?

Comment: You could try doing a regular splitting re regex answers below, and then going through the list to check for erroneous splits. This however might be slow. For speed, I would just split it and then merge the lines upon searching. You should be able to eliminate the vast majority of incorrect splits using a few logic checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty hard problem, and it doesn't have an easy answer. You could try and write a regular expression that captures all of the known cases, but complex regular expressions tend to be hard to maintain and debug. There are a number of existing libraries that may help you with this.  Most notably is [The Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/), which has many tokenizers built in. You can install this with pip e.g.

```
pip install nltk
```

And then getting your sentences would be a fairly straightforward (although highly customizable) affair. Here's a simple example using the provided sentence tokenizer

```
import nltk
with(open('text.txt', 'r') as in_file):
    text = in_file.read()
    sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
```

I'm not entirely clear how your sentences are delimited if not by normal punctuation, but running the above code on your text I get:

> [
>   "I'm having trouble figuring out how I would take a text file of a lengthy document, and append each sentence within that text file to a list.",
>
> "Not all sentences will end in a period, so all end characters would have to be taken into consideration, but there could also be a '.'",
>
> "within a sentence, so I couldn't just cutoff searching through a sentence at a period.",
>
> "I'm assuming this could be fixed by also adding a condition where after the period it should be followed by a space, but I have no idea how to set this up so I get each sentence from the text file put into a list as an element.\n\n"
>   ]

But fails on inputs like: ["This is a sentence with.", "a period right in the middle."]

while passing on inputs like: ["This is a sentence wit.h a period right in the middle"]

I don't know if you're going to get much better than that right out of the box, though. From the nltk code:

> A sentence tokenizer which uses an unsupervised algorithm to build
>   a model for abbreviation words, collocations, and words that start
>   sentences; and then uses that model to find sentence boundaries.
>   This approach has been shown to work well for many European
>   languages.

So the nltk solution is actually using machine learning to build a model of a sentence. Much better than a regular expression, but still not perfect. Damn natural languages. >:(

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

First read the text file into a container.
Then use regular expressions to parse the document.
This is just a sample on how split() methods can be used for breaking the strings

```
import re
file = open("test.txt", "r")
doclist = [ line for line in file ]
docstr = '' . join(doclist)
sentences = re.split(r'[.!?]', docstr)
```

Comment: Gosh, really? Can you be more specific? This isn't really a very helpful answer, as written.

Comment: There you go. I have put some sample. re.split(..) splits does the job and returns a list

Comment: Right, but the OP mentioned that there could be `.` dots in the sentences.

Comment: re.split() here splits the strings on seeing any of dots, question marks and exclamation marks and returns the list 
the [] is where you give the range of characters to split the string
Normally dots, qn marks and exclamation marks are the sentence breaker. So i put these characters

Comment: Yup, I understand regular expressions. But your expression will split on the wrong dots too.

Comment: Hmm.. Yes
I didnt consider that. THnx for pointing that out